# JQuery: to change the element value whenever delete button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I want to change the element(modeflag) value='D' when ever the checkbox is checked and delete button is clicked. In this below code, the value is working good if I select one checkbox. But not working when more than one checkbox is checked. It always changes the first element value to 'D'. I do not know JQuery. Please help to fix this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
$("#del").on('click', delrow);
});
function delrow() {
    var checks = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" );    
    var chkval = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).val();
    checks.parent().parent().hide();
    if(chkval>0){ $("#md"+chkval).attr('value','D'); }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="rowhide_action.php" method="post" name="save_form">

<input type="button" id="del" value="Delete"></input>


<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Databases</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="db_grid">

<tr id="db_grid_row1">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="1" ></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="db[]" value="Oracle"></input></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="modeflag[]" value="S" id="md1" ></input></td>
</tr>

<tr id="db_grid_row2">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="db[]" value="MySQL"></input></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="modeflag[]" value="S" id="md2"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr id="db_grid_row3">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="db[]" value="Cassandra"></input></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="modeflag[]" value="S" id="md3"></input></td>
</tr>

<tr id="db_grid_row4">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="4"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="db[]" value="Mongo"> </input></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="modeflag[]" value="S" id="md4"></input></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Save"></input></br></br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

post action's rowhide_action.php page code given below.

```
<?php

 @extract($_POST); 

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
 echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: you aren't isolating checkboxes  `var chkval = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).val()` will only return value of the first checkbox in the page that is checked.

Comment: charlietfl, thanks. Could you please tell me how to isolate checkboxes?

Comment: loop over all the collection of `checked` with `each` and use `this` inside `each` to get parent of that instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you're only storing the value of the first matched element, try this:

```
function delrow() {
     var checkedNo= $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).length;
     var checks = [];
     var chkval = [];
     for(i=0;i<=checkedNo;i++){
         checks[i] = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).eq(i);
         chkval[i] = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).eq(i).val();
         checks[i].parent().parent().hide();
         if(chkval[i]>0){ $("#md"+chkval[i]).attr('value','D'); }
     }
    }
```

but easier than that:

```
function delrow() {
    $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).each(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        if($(this).val()>0){ $("#md"+$(this).val()).attr('value','D'); }
    });
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot Amin Jafari. It is working good. I just changed the "#md"+chkval to "#md"+chkval[i]  and i=0;i<=checkedNo;i++ to i=0;i<checkedNo;i++. Appreciate your help.

Comment: the second is also working good and easier. thanks again Amin Jafari.